# denied new File in nodejs nextjs

Tags: node.js, next.js

try to move fs to formdata in nextjs nodejs and use new File

```
    const image = fs.readFileSync(filepath || '');
    const body = new FormData();
    const blob = new Blob([image]);
    const file = new File([blob], originalFilename || '');
    body.append('file', file);
```

but got this error

```
ReferenceError: File is not defined
```

Can I use new File in node js ? or any other solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS does not support the `new File()` syntax because it is a browser API. You should instead be using the [filesystem module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). Here is an example:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

fs.appendFile('example.txt', 'Hello World!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

If you are using the `async/await` syntax for asynchronous operations inside your application, you can use it like in the example below:

```js
const fs = require("fs/promises");

const saveFile = async (file, content) => {
  try {
    await fs.appendFile(file, content);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Of course the above approach only works when on the server, like in a server action or a route handler. When on the client side you can still use the `new File()` syntax.

---

PS: If you are deploying on Vercel, the above approach **will not work**, because their filesystem is read-only.